# Не синхронизируется "Мой склад" и modX

Tags: php, modx

Есть сайт на modX, нужно подтянуть товары с "мой склад"
Использую сниппет "[syncMoySklad]". Есть ресурс "Категории", у него нажимаю кнопку "синхронизация">"мой склад">"синхронизация" после чего открывается окно и идут запросы на получение категорий товаров, но в один момент все стопорится и на экране происходит следующая картина.
Что мне делать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.